# How to find non-existing tables in user defined functions?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server lets me drop tables and views that are still referenced by user defined functions without any issues:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (Value INT NOT NULL)
GO
CREATE FUNCTION DoSomething(@foo INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT * FROM SomeTable)
END
GO
DROP TABLE SomeTable
```

Executing "DoSomething" will always fail now.
Is there any way to check **all** user defined functions on the server if they are still executable?

For stored procedures we use `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` in combination with some dynamic SQL. But this does not work for functions unfortunately.

Comment: Look at using *schema binding* to avoid such issues. using `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` should give you what you need.

Comment: You should look into avoiding table access in UDF functions altogether

Comment: also, what's with the random dropping of tables

Comment: As @Stu mentions, if integrity between your objects is important, then use `SCHEMABINDING`. Then you *can't* `DROP` (and sometimes change) objects until those "bound" to it are. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hPKUCQ11)

Comment: *"You should look into avoiding table access in UDF functions altogether"* there is nothing wrong with table access in UDFs, @siggemannen ; though they should really be an iTVF. The OP's exactly actually makes no sense unless `SomeTable` only has one column, and can only ever contain 1 row.

Comment: @Stu sys.sql_expression_dependencies does not help here unfortunately, since the dependency is deleted the moment "SomeTable" is dropped.

Comment: @Andreas - not so, the dependency belongs to the function, not the table.

Comment: `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_entity_name IS NOT NULL
  AND referenced_id IS NULL;` works fine. YOu could easily change `referenced_entity_name IS NOT NULL` to `referenced_entity_name = N'SomeTable'`.

Comment: if everything fails, you can probably fetch parameters from sys.parameters and then construct some dummy SELECTs that tests function call with NULLs

Comment: @siggemannen I thought about creating test-calls, but chances are that I do create other errors with this approach (by passing values the function does not expect). And this approach will not find issues in statements "hidden" in if-clauses that are not executed (I tried that).

Comment: @Stu My mistake, you are correct. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the following example query specifically for user-defined functions:

```
select o.[name]
from sys.objects o
where exists (
  select * from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d 
  where d.referencing_id = o.object_id
    and o.type = 'FN' and o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    and d.referenced_id is null and d.referenced_entity_name is not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use a script or query to check if user-defined functions (UDFs) are still executable after dropping tables or views that they depend on. One common method is to use a script that analyzes the dependencies and checks for issues. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it:

Use the sys.sql_expression_dependencies system catalog view to identify the dependencies of UDFs. Specifically, you're interested in the referenced_id column, which will contain the ID of the object being referenced.

Query the UDFs and their dependencies to check if any of the referenced objects (like tables or views) have been dropped. You can do this by joining sys.sql_expression_dependencies with sys.objects.

Here's an example query that checks if any UDFs are referencing dropped tables or views:

```
SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(udf.object_id) AS UDF_Name,
CASE WHEN t.name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Table ' + t.name
     WHEN v.name IS NOT NULL THEN 'View ' + v.name
     ELSE 'Other Object' END AS Referenced_Object,
CASE WHEN t.name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Dropped'
     WHEN v.name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Dropped'
     ELSE 'OK' END AS Status
FROM sys.objects AS udf
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS dep
     ON udf.object_id = dep.referencing_id
LEFT JOIN sys.tables AS t
     ON dep.referenced_id = t.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.views AS v
     ON dep.referenced_id = v.object_id
WHERE udf.type = 'FN' -- UDFs
     AND (t.name IS NULL OR t.type = 'U') -- Filter out non-table references
     AND (v.name IS NULL OR v.type = 'V') -- Filter out non-view references
     AND (t.name IS NULL OR v.name IS NULL); -- Filter out objects that still exist
```

This query will return a list of UDFs along with the status of their referenced objects. UDFs that have "Dropped" in the Status column are the ones with dropped table or view references.

Remember to run this query in the context of the database where your UDFs are defined.

By regularly running such a query, you can proactively identify UDFs that may have issues due to dropped dependencies and take appropriate action to fix or replace them.

Comment: Thank you!
The script itself contains some issues though: it finds functions that do not have any references, it has issues with references to other functions and the column "status" is inverted.

Comment: Smells like ChatGPT?